# Standard library function to create array of indices whose corresponding value is a given number

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, std

I've got a C-style array called `board` that contains some `char`'s. I'm trying to create a `std::array` or `std::vector` (either would be fine, although `std::array` would be preferable) to store all the indices of `board` that are a certain value (in my case, `0`).
This code I wrote is functional and works well:

```
std::vector<int> zeroes;
zeroes.reserve(16);
//board has 16 elements, so zeroes.size() will never be larger than 16.
//I used this reserve for speedup - the compiler doesn't require it.
for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
{
    if (board[i] == 0)
    {
        zeroes.push_back(i);
    }
}
```

However, from past experience, whenever a `std` function exists that could replace part of my code, it is terser and hence stylistically preferred and also faster. My function seems like a fairly basic operation - I know there is a standard function* to access the index of an array that contains a value when that value only occurs once** in the array. So, is there a standard function to create an array of the indices that contain a value, assuming that more than one such index exists?

---

* Technically, two nested function calls: `int x = std::distance(board, std::find(board, board + 16, 0));`. See [the accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909784/how-do-i-find-a-particular-value-in-an-array-and-return-its-index).
** Well, it still works if more than one index with the desired value is present, but it returns only the first such index, which isn't very useful in my context.

---

Edit:
As one of the answers misunderstood the question, I'll clarify what I'm seeking. Let's say we have:

```
char board[16] = {0, 2, 0, 4,
                  2, 4, 8, 2,
                  0, 0, 8, 4,
                  2, 0, 0, 2};
```

Now, the indices which I'm looking for are `{0, 2, 8, 9, 13, 14}` because `board[0] = 0`, `board[2] = 0`, `board[8] = 0`, etc. and these are the only numbers which satisfy that property.

Comment: Boost.ranges can do that.

Comment: I was thinking `boost::filter_iterator`

Comment: That code looks fine, except for the initial call to `zeroes.reserve(16)`. The calls to `push_back` will adjust the size of `zeroes` as needed, and when it's finished, `zeroes.size()` will tell you how many indices are there.

Comment: @PeteBecker I put the reserve(16) in for computational speedup - that way, it doesn't have to waste time dynamically resizing the array when I already know an upper bound on the array's size. It works without the reserve, but I'll be calling this function frequently enough to make the reserve worth the typing - just edited the post to clarify

Comment: Yes, calling `reserve()` is okay. Too long a day.

Comment: Having now seen two answers with solutions that work, I'd stick with your original code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution using `std::iota` and `std::remove_if`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main () {
  const std::size_t board_size = 16;
  char board [board_size] = {
    0, 2, 0, 4,
    2, 4, 8, 2,
    0, 0, 8, 4,
    2, 0, 0, 2
  };

  // Initialize a zero-filled vector of the appropriate size.
  std::vector<int> zeroes(board_size);

  // Fill the vector with index values (0 through board_size - 1).
  std::iota(zeroes.begin(), zeroes.end(), 0);

  // Remove the index values that do not correspond to zero elements in the board.
  zeroes.erase(std::remove_if(zeroes.begin(), zeroes.end(), [&board] (int i) {
    return board[i] != 0;
  }), zeroes.end());

  // Output the resulting contents of the vector.
  for (int i : zeroes) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Output of the program ([demo](https://ideone.com/6Nn1Qn)):

```
0
2
8
9
13
14
```

Comment: good move using iota instead of generating the indicies yourself